# Convert to community wiki, or just close?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, not-constructive

I just found [this fairly old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2839163/1858225), which is pretty clearly more of a discussion than a useful technical question-and-answer.

I would simply flag it to be closed as not constructive, but it's an interesting question with interesting answers, so I honestly think that would be a shame. There are already several comments saying that it should be converted to a community wiki, and as there are 27 answers, it's pretty close to reaching the magic 30-answer everything's-a-wiki threshold.

So...should this be converted, or simply closed?

Comment: It's already wikied, and it has been for 3 years...

Comment: When you reach 3k, you can democratically cast [close votes](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @Richard I meant that the answers should be collected into a single wiki-answer (or all answers should just be wiki'd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not constructive, although it probably was okay when it was originally asked.  So regardless, close it.

I can't speak to whether in an ideal world a question like this should be a CW.  There shouldn't be further activity on it so I don't think this is a good time in the question's life to say "let's answer it collaboratively!"

Comment: I flagged it, but I think it's worthwhile content and belongs *somewhere*. I suppose it's safe for now as a closed question, since closed != deleted, but if it were asked today, I'd vote for migration, perhaps to Programmers.

Comment: Some questions are locked but preserved for "historical content."  This is a candidate but I don't know the process for that (I think it's just a mod designating it as such).  Also closed doesn't mean should be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, for questions from 3 years ago that are very interesting and were appropriate at the time they were posted I usually see a historical lock. It would be nice if the same thing applied here.